# Help Needed With (I thought) Basic mod_rewrite Setup

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I run my own server at home. I am attempting to do a mod_rewrite but I cannot seem to get it to work correctly.

Say my url is "http://www.site.com/". I have a user set up, whose public_html directory is serving pages; let's say that url is "http://www.site.com/~myUser/theDirectory/". What I am trying to do is set it so that when you type in "http://www.site.com/theDirectory/" it will actually serve the pages out of "http://www.site.com/~myUser/theDirectory/", but look like its coming from "http://www.site.com/theDirectory/". I edited my /etc/apche2/sites-enabled/default file and added these lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^theDirectory/$ /home/myUser/public_html/~myUser/theDirectory/
```

I also tried various versions of the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/theDirectory/$ /home/myUser/public_html/theDirectory/
RewriteRule ^/var/www/html/theDirectory/$ /home/myUser/public_html/theDirectory/
```

I also made sure that the rewrite module was enabled. At first, I was getting this error:

```
[Fri Jun 17 18:11:35 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/theDirectory
```

So I created that file, and now I am getting this error:

```
[Fri Jun 17 23:15:45 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/theDirectory/
```

So, I'm not really sure where to go from here. Any and all advice will be appreciated. Thanks for taking the time to read.

Have a great day  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your virtual host configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/theDirectory(/.*)$ /home/myUser/public_html/theDirectory$1 [L]
```

Comment: I am getting confused by your use of "/home/myUser/public_html/~myUser/theDirectory/" when it is"/home/myUser/public_html/theDirectory/". Would you please clarify?

Comment: @Brian - Look at your example above. You wrote `/home/myUser/public_html/~myUser/theDirectory/` in the first example. I wasn't sure which one to use so I went with that one. I'll fix my example.

Comment: I added your example, and I got this error "Syntax error on line 32 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl: RewriteBase: only valid in per-directory config files". So I wrapped the example in <Directory /></Directory> dilemeters and I am back to getting the "You don't have permission to access /theDirectory/ on this server." error. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to place it in a `.htaccess` and outside of the Directory directive. If you want to place it directly in the Apache config, you could remove the RewriteBase line and change the RewriteRule to read `RewriteRule ^theDirectory(/.*)?$ /home/myUser/public_html/theDirectory$1 [L]`.

Comment: I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong. I removed the lines from the default site-enabled file, and placed in my http.conf file, and I am still getting the error "[Sat Jun 18 00:12:04 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/cloud/" in the apache2 error log file. I'm about ready to wack my server with a stick.

Comment: @Brian - Would you be able to add the content of the config file to your question so I can see it? I've tested the solution above on my server before posting it and it worked great. Perhaps there's something else. If you pointed your browser to "http://example.com/theDirectory/" and got an error pointing to "/var/www/cloud" something else is wrong.

Comment: Oops ... I mistyped "cloud" when I was supposed to type "theDirectory". I get that working on two things at once. Here is what I have in my /etc/apache2/http.conf file:

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond /home/myUser/public_html/theDirectory/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/myUser/public_html/theDirectory/$1 [L]

Comment: @Brian - It's wrong. I'll update my example above. You should have removed the RewriteCond and Updated the RewriteRule as per my previous comment.

Comment: Well, I'm still getting that error. I won't bug you anymore tonight, but I really do appreciate your help with this. I'll plug away with it to see what the issue may be. Thanks again, and have a great night.   :-)

Comment: @Brian - Can you post the error (copy/paste) so that "cloud" isn't part of it this time? ;) It could be permissions too.

Comment: Gotcha, this is what is showing in my /var/log/apache2/error.log file: "[Sat Jun 18 00:47:44 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/theDirectory/". Now, just to clarify, am I, or am I not supposed to have an actual directory named "theDirectory" in /var/www ?

Comment: @Brian - You don't want a directory in there.

Comment: I tried it both ways, when I don't have a "/var/www/theDirectory" directory, this is the error I get in my error.log file: "[Sat Jun 18 00:53:55 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/theDirectory".

Comment: Try adding a / right after the ^ in RewriteRule: `RewriteRule ^/theDirectory(/.*)$ /home/myUser/public_html/theDirectory$1 [L]`.

Comment: Nope, same error. F.Y.I., I am using Ubuntu 10.04, if that makes  difference.

Comment: That's odd. It looks like Apache is ignoring the rewrite directives completely. Are they inside the <Directory> directive for the /var/www folder? Do you have virtual hosts setup? Is it setup in with the right one? Is mod_rewrite enabled? You could look at RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel and see if it logs anything. The bottom line is the config is clearly ignored by Apache. It doesn't matter that you're on Ubuntu.

Comment: They are not inside a <Directory> directive, my http.conf file just has your two lines. I do have virtual hosts set up, and I believe it is on the correct one. Yes, mod_rewrite is enabled (rewrite.load file). I enabled the RewriteLog 'RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log" - RewriteLogLevel 9', but no events are being recorded.

Comment: @Brian - So it's obvious that the problem at this point isn't the rewrite but rather that it's being ignored by PHP. Is it possible that http.conf isn't being included? Shouldn't it be httpd.conf? You should make sure that there's a Include http.conf somewhere in your main Apache config file.

Comment: Yes, I have been neglecting to include the 'd'. My file is, indeed, httpd.conf, and in my apache2.conf, there is a line that reads "Include /etc/apache2/httpd.conf". I am as perplexed as you are, but thanks for all of your help.

Comment: @Brian - Perhaps you should place the content of the httpd.confirm file inside the VirtualHost. It's probably ignored because of that reason.

Comment: I'll be dammed ... that was it. I really cannot thank you enough for all the time you spent on this, I really appreciate it, THANKS! I hope you have a great weekend.

Comment: @Brian - You too. I'm glad I was able to help you.